# Angular5 bundled.min.js is throwing app-root error included as a iframe in jsp page

Tags: javascript, angular, jsp, iframe, angular5

i'm adding an angular bundledjs in the JSP page as an iframe and i'm getting the following error Error: The selector "app-root" did not match any elements.

index.html:

```
<body>
<script type="text/javascript" src= "stackoverflow.js"</script>
<app-root></app-root>
</body>
```

I added bootstrap in the appModule as well. Not sure what am i doing 
   wrong. Individually when i run this angular app locally i dont see any errors, only when i added .min.js in the JSP as an iframe, this issue occurs.

Comment: Did you ever determine a solution for this? I'm getting the exact same issue: No error when hitting index.html directly, but I get the app-root error when loading that into an iframe.

Comment: I don't have any update on it yet. Please let me know if you have any findings?